# add LedgerTrans.DocumentNum field to BankAccountStatment report

Tags: axapta, microsoft-dynamics, ax

I want to add LedgerTrans.DocumentNum field to BankAccountStatment report

BankAccountStatment report has a datasource "BankAccountTable"

How can I perfrom this?

Note: LedgerTrans.DocumentNum can be reached through BankAccoutTrans.AccountId = BankAccountTable.AccountId then LedgerTrans.voucher = BankAccountTrans.Voucher

Answer (score 0):

You can try declaring `LedgerTrans ledgerTrans;` in `classDeclaration` and adding following code in the report's `fetch` method before calling `element.send(bankAccountTrans)`:

```
select firstonly ledgerTrans
    where ledgerTrans.TransDate     == bankAccountTrans.TransDate
       && ledgerTrans.Voucher       == bankAccountTrans.Voucher
       && ledgerTrans.DocumentNum   != "";
```

After that you'd only need to add a new display field in the `ReportDesign\AutoDesignSpecs\Body:_2` section with the following code:

```
//BP Deviation Documented
display DocumentNum documentNum()
{
    return ledgerTrans.DocumentNum;
}
```

I didn't try it but it should work. As an alternative you can declare ledgerTrans in the `fetch` method, add `element.send(ledgerTrans)` after selecting ledgerTrans, and add a standard `String` field in the section mentioned above, `Table`=LedgerTrans, `DataField`=DocumentNum. Then no display method is needed.

P.S. I assumed you're using AX 2009 but for other versions of AX the logic remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

This is simple:

```
display DocumentNum documentNum()
{
     return (select firstonly DocumentNum from ledgerTrans
         where ledgerTrans.TransDate     == bankAccountTrans.TransDate
            && ledgerTrans.Voucher       == bankAccountTrans.Voucher
            && ledgerTrans.DocumentNum   != "").DocumentNum;
}
```

Drag the method to the desired print location.